# c++: unable to match function definition to an existing declaration

Tags: c++, visual-studio-2012, template-classes

HERE IS WHERE HOW I DECLARED IT IN THE PUBLIC OF "template"

```
void print();
```

---

HERE IS TO PRINT

```
template<class T>
T XArray<T>::print()
{

    for ( int i = 0; i < size; ++i)
        cout << Array[i] << " ";
    cout << "\n\n";

}
```

I don't know what I'm doing wrong.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your definition is saying that print returns a `T`, but your declaration says it return `void`.
Change it to

```
template<class T>
void XArray<T>::print()
```